# How to make the compiler check that classes implement static methods / constructors

Tags: java, class, reflection, groovy, constructor

I have an Interface IExample and a few classes that implement this interface. Next I have a list containing some of these classes like

```
List<Class> classes = new List();
classes.add(Class1)
classes.add(Class2)
/...
```

`Class1` and `Class2` both implement IExample. Later on at runtime I have a variable containing one of the classes of the `classes` list: `Class specialClass = Class2 //Class2 chosen randomly`.

What I want do to now is create a new instance of this `specialClass` like

```
IExample myNewInstance = specialClass.newInstance(...)
```

I can implement the constructors and also static methods (if that helps) of all the given classes. But how do I enforce that each class implementing the Interface `IExample` implements a specific constructor or a static method with a specified signature (would also solve this problem).
Because if I can't do this I have to do it like:

```
switch(specialClass) {
    case Class1:
         //do some work with constructor of Class1
    case Class2:
         //do some work with constructor of Class2
    //and so on
}
```

And that would mean, when adding new Classes I not only have to write the new `ClassX`, adding it to the `classes` list and I'm fine, but also having to add a new case to the switch statement. I would like to avoid that.

How can I do this or does my question imply some general misconception?

Comment: Could you not make each class extend a base abstract class that contains this constructor and method?

Comment: Well you're using reflection so you could check if the class (Class) has a specific static method and constructor you want based on the name and/or parameters it should have. But it smells like bad over-generic design, you don't want this. Note that this would be a runtime check, you can't catch it at compile time.

Comment: You mean implementing the constructor in the abstract class? But I want to call the constructors of the concrete classes, I cannot provide a "default" constructor. Each concretes class' constructor MUST be called (at least indirect). @Gimby: I want to catch it at compile time, so that later on if someone adds a new class to the list he sees immediatly "oh, I have to implement a constructor with this signature". So I guess using reflection in this way it's not possible?

Comment: Nope, and I don't believe what you want is possible at all. Constructors are a little different if you switch to using an abstract base class, but static methods no way. I wouldn't know why you would want to enforce that, I'd think you want to NOT use a static method if you want implementing classes to provide an implementation. Do it the OO way.

Comment: The only way I see for checking such a constraint at compile time is to annotate all these classes with a custom annotation and let a annotation processor do the checks (see package [`javax.annotation.processing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html)).

Comment: Why not just have a regular `init()` method in `IExample` that you call explicitly after constructing it?

Comment: @ataylor: you mean an non static `init()` method that the classes have to implement? I don't see how this helps me yet, because I have problems instantiating the classes so that the compiler sees I'm doing it correct. If I was able to instantiate them I can use init() but then I have no problem anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, Groovy doesn't seem to catch the type error in `Class<? extends IExample> specialClass = someClassThatDoesntImplementIExample`, although Java does.  You could enforce this constraint at runtime by using `Collections.checkedList(..., IExample)`.

Comment: @valenterry, i think @ataylor meant to have the constructor logic inside the `init()` method instead of the constructor. What do you want to put in the constructor that can't be in a `init()` method?

Comment: @Will P, but how do i call the init() if it is not a static method? I don't have any instance of the class i want to create yet.

Comment: @valenterry Create the instance using `clazz.newInstance()`, then call `init()`. The `init()` would be enforced by every class implementing a interface which has the `init()` method.

Comment: @Will P, That's it! Now I got your advice. =) Thx, this solves my Problem.